# jquery /ajax post list is being posted with [ ] in the end

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm posting an jquery/ajax with django end sending a dict 
but im my view I'm getting the areas like this  {'areas[]': ['4', '5'],...} Myform its ok but the areas to get the key I have to use 'areas[]'
How can I get just like this 'areas' without the brackets ?
if I try to use the variable areas inside form.is_valid() it become None 
why does it happen?
thanks

```
     var application_area = "/api/application-area/"


    $.getJSON(application_area, function(area){
        try{

            (function ($, undefined) {
                $.jstree.defaults.conditionalselect = function () { return true; };

                $.jstree.plugins.conditionalselect = function (options, parent){                                                                         
                    this.activate_node = function (obj, e) {                                                  
                        if(this.settings.conditionalselect.call(this, this.get_node(obj))) {                            
                            parent.activate_node.call(this, obj, e);
                        }        
                    };
                };

            })(jQuery);               
            createJSTree(area)                
        }catch(ex){
            console.log(ex)        
        }
    });


    function createJSTree(area) {            
        $("#search_tree").keypress(function(){
            var searchString = $(this).val();
            $("#tree").jstree('search', searchString);
        })                      

        $('#tree').jstree({                    
            "conditionalselect" : function (node) {
                if(node.parents.length == 1 || node.parents.lengoh == 2 ||  node.parents.length == 3 ){
                    return false
                }
                else if(node.parents.length == 4){
                    if(this.get_selected().length >= 10){
                        if(this.is_selected(node)){
                            return true
                        }
                        return false
                    }else{
                        return true
                    };
                }                     
            },               
            'core': {
                "multiple": true,  
                "check_callback" : true,              
            "themes": {
                "theme": "classic",
                "dots": true,
                "variant": "small",
                "icons": false,
                "responsive":true,
            },
            'data':area
            },
            "search":{
                "case_insensitive":true,
                "show_only_matches":true,

            },                
            "checkbox": {
                "keep_selected_style": false,
                "three_state" : true,

            },

            "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox", "search","conditionalselect", "dnd", "conditionalteste"],
        })                                
    }    

    var list_area  = []

    $("#tree").on("changed.jstree", function(e, node){            
        list_area = node.instance.get_selected(false)
        console.log(list_area)
    })


    $('#documet').ready(function(){

        console.log(list_area)        

        $('#project_form_id').on('submit', function(event){
            //event.preventDefault()

            var form = $(this)                

            //var detail = {
              //  myForm: form.serializeArray(),
                //'areas':list_area 
            //} 


            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'project_create' %}",
                method: "POST",
                data:{'areas':list_area},
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},        
                success: function(response){
                    console.log('success')
                    console.log(list_area)
                    $('#project_form_id').reset(); 
                },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                    //$("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);

                }
            });

        })
    })
    </script>
```

my view

```
    def projectcreate(request):
        researcher = Researcher.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)          

        if request.method == 'POST':           
        areas = request.POST.getlist('areas[]')               
        print(areas)
        form = ProjectForm(researcher, request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)            


        if form.is_valid():
            print(areas)
            print('true')
            project = Project()

            project.with_ict = form.cleaned_data['with_ict']
            project.with_company = form.cleaned_data['with_company']
            project.for_company = form.cleaned_data['for_company']
            project.predominant_area = form.cleaned_data['']
            project.title = form['title']
            project.ubc = form['ubc']
            project.conclusion_date = form.cleaned_data['conclusion_date']
            project.category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            project.has_patent = form.cleaned_data['has_patent']
            project.tech_transf = form.cleaned_data['tech_transf']
            project.tech_transf_date = form.cleaned_data['tech_transf_date']
            project.stage = form.cleaned_data['stage']
            project.result = form.cleaned_data['result']
            project.researcher  = researcher
            project.save()
            if areas:
            for area in areas:
                project.application_area.add(area)
        else:
            print('false')

        company_form = CompanyForm(request.POST or None, prefix='company')
        if company_form.is_valid():
            company = Company()
            company.name = company_form.cleaned_data['name']
            company.cnpj = company_form.cleaned_data['cnpj']
            company.email = company_form.cleaned_data['email']
            company.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_list'))
        else:
        form = ProjectForm(researcher)
        company_form = CompanyForm(prefix='company')
        context = {
            'form':form,
            'company_form':company_form
        }
        html_form = render_to_string('researcher/project/project_form.html',
            context,
            request=request,
        )
        return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})
```

html form

```
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h2 class="text-center">Adicionar Projeto</h2>
        </div>
        <h2 class="text-center card-title" style="padding-top:10px">{{object}}</h2>        
        <form id="project_form_id" method="post" action="{% url 'project_create' %}" style="padding:20px" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.title }}
            </div>             

            <div id="company_id">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{company_form.management_form}}
                {{ company_form }}
            </div>                                      
            </div>                          

            </div>         

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
                {{form.ubc.label}}:
            </label>
            {{form.ubc}}
            </div>
            <hr>
            <input type="search" id="search_tree" placeholder="Pesquisar Area de aplicação"  class="form-control" value="" required="required" title="">
            <br>
            <div id="tree"></div>            
            <br>
            <input type="search" id="search_cnpq" placeholder="Pesquisar Area de conhecimento"  class="form-control" value="" required="required" title="">
            <br>
            <div id="cnpq"></div>
            <br>
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Criar" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add the form html too.

Comment: Where `list_area` is defined in the js?

Comment: sorry I put the right code now

Comment: Ok, basically `areas` is an array, so why not getting it with the `[]`, in some cases it have worked for me, in others not. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist